# How can I make an object show up on different layers

Tags: layers

How can I make an object show up on different layers without having to copy it? E.g. I have an object animated and I want it to show up on multiple layers.

Comment: I know I just asked it again so you don't have to look up the answer there (It is not mentioned in the accepted answer). It shouldn't be an exact duplicate. Thanks for answering

Answer (score 12, accepted):

<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>LMB</kbd> on the layer boxes in the `Relations` section of `Properties`->`Object`.
[image]

Or in 3d view hit <kbd>M</kbd> in `Object` mode, and <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>LMB</kbd> on the layer boxes there

Answer (score 3):

Select your object, hotkey <kbd>m</kbd>, and then <kbd>Shift</kbd> left-click on whatever layers you want it to appear in. 

NOTE: if you do have your object in multiple layers, you'll generally also want to add the camera and lights to those (multiple) layers as well when compositing.