# Same object with modifiers in different layers

Tags: render-layers, layers

How to use the same object with modifiers  applied in different layers ?
I don't want to duplicate object and move it in another layer. I want Blender to use same amount of memory for that object. So that I could use different compositing in another layer but memory and CPU computing should stay optimized as possible.

Comment: Do you want it to be [assigned to multiple Scene layers](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/969/how-can-i-make-an-object-show-up-on-different-layers?rq=1) ?

Comment: Yes, object with same memory in Blender to speed up postprocessing nad rendering. But, object in second layer will be differently made in compositor and rendered at different time. If I hit M on object +Shift to another layer it disappers from current layer.

Comment: I don't quite understand how the object dissappears from the 1st layer if assigned  *also* to 2-nd. It will be present in scene if either one of layers selected. For rendering, as is said in the linked thread, you might want to assign lamps to several layers too, so that object to be seen. If you're talking about [Render Layers](http://www.blender.org/manual/render/post_process/layers.html), then you should also `Shift` click them too

Comment: Yes, my mistake Shift+LeftMB with the camera and light, otherwise it's not rendered. Thanks. So, that method doesn't duplicate the object?

Comment: No, it doesn't - assigning it to layers makes it to be [displayed on more than one layer](http://www.blender.org/manual/editors/3dview/layers.html?highlight=scene%20layers#moving-objects-between-layers), not to be duplicated.